# Adding Taxonomy Image to taxonomy loop

Tags: php, taxonomy, tags

I'm using the code below to show six random tags, adding a class on an `<a>` tag.

```
$args = array(
'taxonomy'   => 'post_tag',
'hide_empty' => 0
);
$tags = get_terms( $args );
$class_name = 'my-custom-class-name';

if ( ! empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
shuffle( $tags );   
foreach( array_slice( $tags, 0, 6 ) as $tag ) {
    printf( '<a class="%1$s" href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
        sanitize_html_class( $class_name ),
        get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
        sprintf( __( '%s') , $tag->name )
    );
  }
}
```

I'm also using a plugin called [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/). This plugin allows me to place images with my tags.

`wp_get_attachment_image()` should display the taxonomy image. My problem is that I don't know how to place that line in the code above without messing something up.

The html looks like this:

`<a class="class-name" href="taxonomy-url">taxonomy-name<a>`

I want to achieve this, with the `<img>` tag's class being different from the `<a>` tag's class:

`<a class="class-name" href="taxonomy-link"><img src="taxonomy-image-url" class="class-name"> taxonomy-name</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You should you this plug in instead: [Category Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/)

And don't be shy learning and using printf, it's worth.

```
printf( '<a class="%1$s" href="%2$s"><img class="img-class" src="%4$s" <h3>%3$s</h3></a>',
    sanitize_html_class( $class_name ),
    get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
    sprintf( __( '%s') , $tag->name ),
    z_taxonomy_image_url($tag->term_id, 'thumbnail' )
);
```

A note fore easier debugging, you can use `var_dump($tag)` inside the foreach loop to now exactly what `$tag` object has.